# Symfony2 swiftmailer temporarily disable spool

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I want store some emails in the spool to send later and send some emails immediately.

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: if you really need to store some email to send it later (like for a newsletter) is better to store it on a database and send it at the prefixed time using a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is not possible with the Spooler. You have to change your script and send the Emails only if it should be send. Then you don't need that function.

Then question is why do your need such a function to delay an E-Mail. On that point where you send an Email with a delayed option you can check and send that E-Mail first if the time for the delay is over.

Comment: I need this because we ask me to do that.We need to store some email in a folder for send it later with a job but we need too send some email in real time. It's strange that swiftmailer can not do this.

Comment: I think that is possible but I don't have the solution. The way for solution is response to 'how to disabling pool swifterMailer' and after 'how to change dynamically this disabling/enabling config in rela time'.